VS Code: How to automatically remove double spaces on save?
I want VS Code to automatically correct spaces when saving a JSON file (I do not want this rule to be applied to any other types of files, but this is not crucial)
Example:
// before saving
{
  "someField":       "value"
}

// after saving
{
  "someField": "value"
}

I've searched the internet, and there are lots of articles on how to remove trailing spaces automatically when saving a file. But this is not the case
Solution that worked for me
I added this rule to my settings.json:
"[json]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}


Do you have json.format.enabled enabled (as well as format on save)? That should handle that.

Let us know if @TimothyG.'s suggestion does not work for you.  It works for me.

@Mark, @TimothyG, thanks for your help. I have actually found another setting, that helpes me in my case (I updated the question). By the way, setting "json.format.enable": true does not help, if I have editor.formatOnSave: false, but the latter solves my problem without any help
